# Function of random variable: Two ways to find the pdf

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, random-functions

Suppose $X$ is a r.v with pdf $f_X(x)$. Let $Y = g(X)$. To find the pdf of $Y$ - $f_Y(y)$. I use one of two ways and **I assume g to be a monotonically increasing function.**

**Method I**

first using the standard change of variable in integration

Since, $dy = g'(x)dx$

$f_X(x) dx = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \frac{dy}{g'(g^{-1}(y))}$. From this I infer that

(1)     $f_Y(y) = \frac{f_X(g^{-1}(y))}{g'(g^{-1}(y))}$

**Method II**

Consider the distribution function of $Y$, $F_{Y}(x)$

$F_{Y}(y) = \mathbb{P}(Y < y) = \mathbb{P}(X < g^{-1}(y)) = F_{X}(g^{-1}(y))$

Now to find pdf of $Y$. I differentiate the distribution function with respect to y and get,

(2)    $\frac{d}{dy} F_{Y}(y) = f_{Y}(y) = f_{X}(g^{-1}(y)).\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)$

**Q1)  My question is that even for monotonically increasing function where method II is applicable (1) and (2) seem to differ. Why?**

**Q2)  Does Method I always yield the right answer for any type of function?**

Comment: Where is the difference? Note that $$\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)=\frac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(y))}.$$

Comment: Oops! my bad, yes I see now. However I still have a question method I doesn't seem to care about whether a function is monotonically increasing or not, but why does that fail if the function is not monotonically increasing?

Comment: In general, if $g$ is monotonic (but potentially decreasing instead of increasing), you have
$$f_Y(y)=\left|\frac{d}{dy}(g^{-1}(y))\right| \cdot f_X(g^{-1}(y)).$$
The situation is more complicated if $g$ is not monotonic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables

Comment: @Prag1: Because if it's not monotonically increasing, it's not invertible.

Comment: Ah I see that now thanks..